# Get all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I know that this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class-1')[0].
```

selects the first `<div>` that has the specify class.

I guess using a `for()` will get  through the whole array of `<div>`.

Can somebody explain how to create that array ?

I will prefer plain Js.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Method `getElementsByClassName()` returns a set of DOM elements that have a certain class name. Here is a canonical example of how to use the returned list of nodes:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class-1");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    // elements[i].style ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by every browser.

Comment: As @Amberlamps noted: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname IE8 and lower do not support it